# JQuery Toggle Slide Function Not Working Quite Right

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm sure this is a simple fix, but I can't figure it out.

When clicked, the following code it MEANT TO turn my hamburger to a 'X' and at the same time create a slide down toggle which opens "header-nav". Once clicked again (now on the 'X'), it turns back into a hamburger and the "header-nav" is slid back up and hidden away....

but...

what it's actually doing is the opposite. It shows the 'X' when it's closed and the hamburger once it's opened. Hmm. Any ideas?

HTML:

```
<div class="skip-links">
            <a href="#header-nav" class="skip-link skip-nav">
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
                <span class="icon"></span>
                <span class="label">MENU</span>
            </a>
</div> </div>
```

CSS:

```
.skip-link.skip-nav span {
   display: block;
   position: absolute;
   height: 3px;
   width: 30%;
   border-radius: 9px;
   opacity: 1;
   left: 0;
   -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
   -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
   -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
   transform: rotate(0deg);
   -webkit-transition: .25s ease-in-out;
   -moz-transition: .25s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: .25s ease-in-out; 
   transition: .25s ease-in-out;
}


.skip-link.skip-nav span:nth-child(1) {
   top: 0px;
   background: #ccc;
}

.skip-link.skip-nav span:nth-child(2),.skip-link.skip-nav span:nth-child(3) {
   top: 10px;
   background: #ccc;
}


.skip-link.skip-nav span:nth-child(4) {
   top: 21px;
   background: #ccc;
}

.skip-link.skip-nav.open span:nth-child(1) {
   top: 18px;
   width: 0%;
   left: 50%;
   background: #000;
}

.skip-link.skip-nav.open span:nth-child(2) {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  background: #000;
}

.skip-link.skip-nav.open span:nth-child(3) {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  background: #000;
}

.skip-link.skip-nav.open span:nth-child(4) {
  top: 18px;
  width: 0%;
  left: 50%;
  background: #000;
} 

.skip-link.skip-nav .label {
    margin-top: 80px;
}
```

JQUERY:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
jQuery('.skip-link.skip-nav').click(function(){
jQuery(this).toggleClass('open');
jQuery('#header-nav').slideToggle(200); 
    }); 
});
```

The thing that seems to be knocking it out is the line:

```
jQuery('#header-nav').slideToggle(200);
```

It works in the opposite with this. Without this is works as it should. But I need this for the "slide" affect.

Comment: Toggling class may make confusion, try using hasClass, addClass and removeClass instead

Comment: your code works fine, look at jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/xpkFf/333/

Comment: @AliTorabi I presume you mean instead of the 'toggleClass' ? If so, unfortunately this doesn't seem to do the trick.

Comment: @loli it seems to work there, but there's nothing to slide down to show the #header-nav (and to see if the 'slide' still works). I will try adding more HTML code to see if that is what affects it. My site is built in Magento, so obtaining the code isn't particularly easy.